# How can I convert .psd files to jpg,pdf and png (RGB/CMYK) using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Can I use multiple variations of the below Imagemagick command to achieve the to convert a psd to png, jpg and pdf with rgb and cmyk settings

convert -colorspace rgb/cmyk original.psd convert.png/jpg/pdf

I am a newbie trying to play with file formats and I also want to convert the output files based on RGB and CMYK.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can try those commands. In general, use `convert input.png ...options... output.png` rather than `convert ...options... input.png output.png` as the later versions of ImageMagick are stricter in the ordering. Try some things and come back if you have a specific question.

Comment: ImageMagick uses Ghostscript for the conversion. Ghostscript cannot handle CMYK with alpha. So you will have to convert to sRGB with your -colorspace sRGB. Don't use -colorspace RGB as that is linear, unless you are on a very old version of ImageMagick. If your results are too dark using RGB, then changes to sRGB. Note that Ghostscript will rasterize your output result and so your output PDF will be a raster image imbedded in a vector PDF shell. It won't preserve vector text.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, Mark and Fred  @fmw42, I have a small question, like, is there a way to preserve the vector text if I convert from psd to pdf.

Comment: Imagemagick is a raster processor. It always converts vectors to raster. So I do not think you can do what you want in Imagemagick. Also Imagemagick has limited functionality with  regard to PSD files.